# Can words in regular languages be generated by automata in a unique way?

Tags: automata-theory, fl.formal-languages

If $L\subset \Sigma^\ast$ is a regular language then it is known that we can find a directed graph (aka automaton) $G$ with edges labelled with symbols from $\Sigma$, an ‘initial’ vertex, and a set of ‘terminal’ vertices, with the property that a word $w$ is in $L$ iff $w$ is the sequence of edge labels along a path from the initial vertex to a terminal vertex.

It’s possible that the same word can appear as a result of different paths in $G$. Can we guarantee that for any regular $L$ we can find a $G$ such that each word in $L$ appears as a path in $G$ in a *unique* way?

(I’m interested in this because I want to know whether the solution to the problem I worked on [here](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2010/08/constraining-types-with-regular.html) applies cleanly to any regular language, or just for a certain class of them.)

Comment: This question doesn't look like a research-level question in TCS. It should perhaps be moved to http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood your question, but wouldn't a Deterministic Finite Automaton do what you want?

Comment: You may be right. I'm not knowledgeable in this area and I've been thinking in terms of generation of strings, not recognition. But now I think about it, you're probably right. I'll mull over it for a little bit.

Comment: Yes, it's straightforward. I just came at this at the wrong angle. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to know that there's also a notion of [ambiguity for regular expressions](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=6789779090132465473). Also, you can [decide ambiguity for NFAs](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=4038507) in $O(n^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

A DFA, as stated, can answer your question.

If you are interested in a small automaton for this task there are three things which comes to mind:

1. DFA can be optimized, so you could find the minimal (state-wise) automaton for the langauge.
2. There exists a different type of automaton called *Unambiguous Finite Automaton* ($UFA$), which is a non deterministic finite automaton which has at most one accepting path for each word.
3. Unlike DFA, UFA optimization is NP-hard hence the minimal automaton for your task is unlikely to be found efficiently for a general language.